# Why does the average kinetic energy of particles in water involve the gas constant?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, gas

I am reading [these lecture notes](https://scholar.harvard.edu/files/schwartz/files/2-diffusion_0.pdf) on statistical mechanics. On page $10$, the author asserts that the average kinetic energy of particles floating in water is given by
$$\frac{3RT}{2N_A},
$$
where $R$ is the ideal gas constant, $T$ is temperature, and $N_A$ is Avogadro's number.

Why is this formula applicable? I know that it works for gases, but particles floating in water are not a gas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ideal gas constant $R$ is a conversion factor between energy and temperature. It is actually a factor that describes the SI system of units (or any other system of units) rather than a factor that describes gasses. Since we use the same units of energy and temperature for gasses and for liquids the conversion factor, $R$, is the same

Comment: Thanks. Could you please clarify why the constant 3/2 remains the same also? As you say, dimensional analysis permits one to guess everything up to a constant. But why the constant is the same as a monatomic gas is unclear to me.

Comment: (In particular, the derivation in the notes appears to be for a particle moving in a 2-d slide of water. But the 3 corresponds to three spatial degrees of freedom. How do we reconcile that?)

Comment: The 3/2 is actually probably not a good approximation for a molecule like water. The professor appears to just be using it for convenience. In an ideal gas there are 3 degrees of freedom (x,y,z translation). In a molecule like water there are those 3 plus 3 vibrational modes and 3 rotational modes. Depending on the temperature some of those may be frozen out. I wouldn't focus on the 3/2, it will not generally be present.

Comment: I think the 3/2 is for the particle moving in water (e.g. dust or dye) and not the water itself. Do you think it's a better approximation in that case?

Comment: @alligator that is certainly possible, I didn't read it too carefully. Whether or not that is a good approximation would depend on the chemical makeup of the dye/dust, but it could indeed be valid for some dyes I assume. In any case, I wouldn't worry too much about the 3/2, it is subject to change and often will be determined empirically